# CREATE TABLE errors out after 1st use?

Tags: php, mysql

This piece of code creates the first table with no problems, but then throws "Error Querying Database 2" which is the error for the second CREATE TABLE query. Syntax looks right, but I'm relatively new to this...

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("localhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass") or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
mysqli_select_db($dbc, "autoim9_codeaic");

$content = "CREATE TABLE content (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), page varchar(255), html longtext)";
mysqli_query($dbc, $content) or die('Error querying database1');

$events = "CREATE TABLE events (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), name varchar(255), date varchar(255), time varchar(255), location varchar(255), html longtext, img varchar(255), link varchar(255), target varchar(255), order int)";
mysqli_query($dbc, $events) or die('Error querying database2');


$spotlight = "CREATE TABLE spotlight (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), title varchar(255), img varchar(255), link varchar(255), target varchar(255), order int)";
mysqli_query($dbc, $spotlight) or die('Error querying database3');
```

Comment: You can find these things out yourself by inspecting `mysqli_error($dbc)` in case of an error.

Answer (score 2):

`date`, `time`, and `order` are reserved keywords in MySQL. You either need to change their names or use backticks (`) to escape them.

```
$events = "CREATE TABLE events (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), name varchar(255), `date` varchar(255), `time` varchar(255), location varchar(255), html longtext, img varchar(255), link varchar(255), target varchar(255), `order` int)";
```

FYI, if you're using `varchar(255)` for every field you probably are doing it wrong. [Date and time fields have their own data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) and should be used accordingly.

Comment: `DATE` and `TIME` although reserved, are actually permitted without quotes for backward compatibility since they're so commonly used as column names.  `ORDER` is the problem here.

Comment: I'm allowing free-form date/time as these fields are for backdating information, not timestamping.

Comment: could I use "sort" instead of order?

Answer (score 1):

"Order" is a reserved word, so you need to enclose in back-ticks (or preferably, choose a slightly different field name).

So it's actually an error in your SQL.